# Python script crashes when executed from server

Tags: python, networkx

I am executing locally a python script through a php exec function and everything works fine.
Now its the time I need to move the project in the server and I am facing some problem when it comes in executing the same python script.

In both cases I have the same version of Python (2.7.3) and all the required libs are installed. 
I have spotted where the issue is created but I can not figure out why. 
Its this line in my python script:

```
import networkx as nx
CG1_nodes=nx.connected_components(G1)[:]
```

It runs successfully in the locally but it crashes in the server. I have found out that if I remove the:

```
[:]
```

then it works. I have also checked the content of G1 and its populated.
Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: I know that the python script crashes.

Comment: How do you know the script crashes?

Comment: I did something very simply. I tried to print a value just after the line of code I show above. Nothing returns. I guess this means that the script stops running just there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're consuming a generator. It's possible that it's has billions of items. If that's the case - python may be out of resources. Make sure you're not overloading the system by checking how big the resulting list will be.

I'd also take a look at problems with slicing in libraries that are used by `networkx` (NumPy? SciPy?). Perhaps try:

```
CG1_nodes=list(nx.connected_components(G1))
```

To avoid slicing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think this is the problem. Then it wouldn't work also locally right? Moreover I don't have so much items inside the list. For sure not billions.

Comment: thanks for your edit. I think it might help. But I don't understand why it runs normally in the local server and gets problems in the server. Do you have any idea? Perhaps some kind of properties I have to change in the server side?

Comment: Same operating systems? Same python version?

Comment: Both python are 2.3.7 and I am running  locally Ubuntu 12.10  and on the server Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (quite old I know!)

Comment: In any case the CG1_nodes=list(nx.connected_components(G1)) helped a lot and solved the problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should check if you have the same version of networkx in both cases.

In older networkx versions `nx.connected_components(G1)` was a list.  In the newer version (1.9.1) it's a generator.  If `X` is a generator, then `X[:]` doesn't work.  But if `X` is a list it does.  So if your machine and the server have different versions, then in one case it would be allowable but not the other.

You "fixed" this by removing the `[:]`, and so `CG1_nodes` is now a generator rather than a list.  As long as your earlier use of it is consistent with a generator, the results would (probably) be the same.  So the two codes would work.  Obviously making it a list explicitly would work, but might be memory intensive.

More details are documented [here](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/api_1.9.html#miscellaneous-changes).  In particular note:

> To recover the earlier behavior, use `list(connected_components(G))`.

I believe the previous version returned the list sorted by decreasing component size.  The new version is not sorted.  If you need it sorted you'll need to do a bit more:

```
sorted(list(nx.connected_components(G)), key = len, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. Very useful comment. Can you please tell me how I can check the version of networkx in Ubuntu?

Comment: in python, you can do `import networkx as nx`  then `print nx.__version__`.  The change occured in version 1.9.1 (I think)

Comment: That was it.  In one OS I have networkx-1.9.1 and the other I have networkx-1.8.1 Very useful comment. Thanks.